# PHP5.3 number_format returns NaN

Tags: php, number-formatting, nan, php-5.3

I have this piece code developed in PHP5.5 **without any issue**. However, when same code is moved to another server in PHP5.3, the number_format() does not return expected value, but return "nan"

This is my code:

```
number_format($num, 2, ".", ",");
```

the variable `$num` is retrieved from database with data type `decimal(25,8)`

What confuse me is that it works for some number, but not some others. Example:

```
$num = 1800.00000000
number_format($num, 2, ".", ",") ==> returns "nan"

$num = 1000.00000000
number_format($num, 2, ".", ",") ==> returns "1,000.00"
```

Is this a common bug in PHP 5.3? Is there any solution for it?

I have google but there is no solution that works for my case so far. The typecast to float or floatval() also not working.

**UPDATE**

The issue happen because of `DateTime::diff()` that is run just before the `number_format` line.

Somehow this function causes issue in PHP5.3 but not in PHP5.5

Once the function is changed by using strtotime() to calculate the difference between 2 dates, everything works normal.

Although, truthfully, i still don't know why the issue happen in the first place. If anyone know about this, please share with me too. Thanks!

Comment: [PHP 5.3 returns `1,800.00`](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c1df059e72923d1011e0e66cfa9416df38b8317f) - "nan" part sounds like javascript to me - are you sure you've got your facts straight?

Comment: Out of fairness to the OP there are scenarios within PHP floating point math that produce `NaN` — earlier versions of PHP had big problems with it. https://3v4l.org/q8Tog

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53735

Comment: @robbieAverill i did use jQuery but only to hide/show the table row. Does that interfere with the PHP number_format? i tried `var_dump(number_format($num,2,'.',','));` the result is `string(3) "nan"` could it be that the issue lies in the database data-type decimal?    @mapek i am using Windows (xampp) in both server though

Comment: Interesting- what is var dump of $num?

Comment: `var_dump($num)` result in `string(13) "1800.00000000"` but as i said above, `number_format(floatval($num),2,'.',',')` and `number_format((float)$num,2,'.',',')` doesn't change anything.

Comment: `var_dump(floatval($num))` result in `float(NAN)`

Comment: Ok, i found the solution. It seems it's because of the code before this one where i am using DateTime::diff(). Somehow this causes issue in PHP5.3. Once i change the function to use strtotime() to calculate the date different, everything works normal. Although, i still don't know why the issue happen in the first place.

Comment: In my case, I am using values from a webservice and somehow getting NaN when I use `number_format(variable_get('deger4deger'),0,",",".")`. PHP guys on Freenode said it's because I am not using integer but it's the same as well when using integer. My PHP version is 7.0.32.